# Delete duplicates from the table pl/sql oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that contains data and fields:

```
contact_id | call_siebel | start_time | operator_text | client_text | client_id | phone_num
```

I found duplicates:

```
SELECT operator_text, client_text, client_id
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY operator_text, client_text, client_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

For example, there are 4 identical data, two of which have the same client_id value
(correct) and the other two have client_id = '-1'. And I need to leave
only one option out of four, whose client_id is filled in correctly.

I wanted to create a test table in which I will enter data with a unique value
client_id from all duplicates that exist, remove duplicates from the main table
data on client_id and in the end just insert from the test table into the main one.

How would it be more correct to insert data from the main table into the test one with a unique
client_id from all duplicates? In my version, I incorrectly implemented GROUP BY:

```
INSERT /*+ append enable_parallel_dml parallel(16)*/
INTO table_test
SELECT
 DISTINCT 
 t.contact_id, 
 t.call_siebel, 
 t.start_time, 
 t.operator_text, 
 t.client_text, 
 t.client_id, 
 t.phone_num
FROM table t
WHERE t.client_id != '-1'
GROUP BY t.operator_text, t.client_text, t.client_id
HAVING COUNT(t.client_id) > 1;
```

After this I could easily finish my job using:

```
DELETE table
WHERE client_id
IN (SELECT t.client_id
FROM table_test t);


INSERT 
INTO table
SELECT *
FROM table_test;
```

Comment: can you share a DB fiddle so we can undestand it better ? what is the output of the group by query you have written and how you determine which one is the correct record ? if there is another record with client id = -1 , how it can be duplicate with client id = XXX for example ?

Comment: @AliFidanli For example, there can be 4 identical data with contact_id, in two of these data is client_id
the same(correct version) and the other two client_id = '-1'. That is my task
is to leave only one correct option out of 4.
But it may also be that there are 2 identical data with contact_id,
and there both have client_id = '-1'. In this case, I need to leave only one of them.

Answer (score 0):

How about skipping that "temporary" table entirely?

Sample data:

```
SQL> select * from test;

 CLIENT_ID OPERATOR_TEXT        CLIENT_TEXT
---------- -------------------- --------------------
         1 a                    a         --> the first two rows 
         1 a                    a         --> are duplicates
        -1 a                    a         --> this is invalid row (because of a negative CLIENT_ID)
         1 b                    c         --> this is OK
```

Delete invalid rows (because of a negative `client_id`) (line #2) and all duplicates (the `rowid` subquery):

```
SQL> delete from test a
  2  where a.client_id < 0
  3     or a.rowid > (select min(b.rowid)
  4                   from test b
  5                   where b.client_id     = a.client_id
  6                     and b.operator_text = a.operator_text
  7                     and b.client_text   = a.client_text
  8                  );

2 rows deleted.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * from test;

 CLIENT_ID OPERATOR_TEXT        CLIENT_TEXT
---------- -------------------- --------------------
         1 a                    a
         1 b                    c

SQL>
```